# Create another website with subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, cpanel, cgi-bin

I want to create one test website to run on my server.
I created subdomain using CPanel. After creating, that folder is empty, with no cgi-bin folder (is this correct behaviour)?
I uploaded WP to that folder, created database, change wp-config.php file.

I tried to copy cgi-bin folder to that subdomain folder, but I keep getting this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /cgi-bin/php5.fcgi/landscape/index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Does someone have idea what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need the cgi-bin folder for a WordPress install on a sub-domain.  What precisely is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I just want to create another WP website, like subdomain, and to access it like test.domain.com, where my subdomain is test. I saw that cgi-bin is missing in subdomain folder, so I just copied the one from root. I just deleted, so I will try again, to see if this helps.

Comment: Strange, I can't access my original domain anymore :/ It reports same 404 error.

Comment: And I forgot to mention, don't know if it matters, but I already have one WP site running on my server (in root folder).

Comment: Yea... idk whats going on, but you do not need any cgi-bin stuff for a WP install.  Installing on a subdomain should have no effect on the original domain.  I would suggest getting the subdomain up and running with a test `index.html` page, and once thats working - go for the full WP install.  It should be just the standard 5-minute install - nothing special.

On a side note, there is a [Wordpress specific stack exchange site.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) which is great for WP specific questions.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with static index.html first, and it worked. once I added wordpress site, it crashed. Thanks Zach, I'll try it one more time.

Comment: so, what kinda error message did you recieve? Most of the time I feel like its issues with wp-config db info